# dom/css: inclose multiple 100% container into a container larger then the viewport(100%)

Tags: html, css, dom, layout

I am looking into a basic DOM layout that lets me put a couple containers that are set `width:100%; height:100%;` in a row so I can let the user scroll between them:

[image: example]

So I have a FRAME that is set to `width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;` and an inclosed CONTAINER that is eg `width:20000px; height:100%;`.
Now I can scroll through the vast landscape of the blue CONTAINER where I would typically have elements absolute positioned in it and could scroll to. So far so good.
Now I have several PAGES that need `width:100%; height:100%;` because of overlapping content in it.

My problem is now that the floated container PAGES will span over the entire 20000px when I set it to `width:100%;` as that is 100% obviously...

How would you display multiple container in a row that are all as wide and as high as the viewport of the browser possibly without any JS hacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could just use fractions for the pages, like `width:33%;` if there are 3 pages, `25%` if there are 4 pages, etc. In order for that to look clean across multiple browsers and window sizes, a little jQuery is the only proper way to handle it:

```
$(function(){
    $('#first_page,#second_page,#third_page').css('width',$(window).width());
});
```

[jQuery width() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: I was really hoping for a none JS solution... but yeas I am afraid jQuery is going to be the solution here

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
* {margin:0; padding:0;}

html, body {height: 100%; }

#frame {height: 100%; width: 100%; background: gray;}

#container {height: 100%; width: 300%; display: table;}

.page {display: table-cell; outline: 2px solid red; outline-offset: -2px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=frame>
  <div id=container>
    <div class=page>
page1
    </div>
    <div class=page>
page2
    </div>
    <div class=page>
page3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe a starting point for recent browsers. Note that a table may overflow its container without affecting its width (gray), causing a scrollbar on html/body. The table-cells are deviding the width equally. But you need to know the amount of pages.

Comment: what browser don't support that? It seems to me `display:table` is what I was looking for

Comment: IE up to and including 7 don't support display:table